# WaitForSingleObject: do not lock a mutex but check the current state?

Tags: c, winapi, mutex

I'm currently using `WaitForSingleObject((HANDLE)handle,INFINITE)` function to mutex-lock some parts of my code.

Now I have a situation where I do not want to lock it but just peek, if it is in the locked-state. Using POSIX I can do that with `pthread_mutex_trylock()` - when it fails, I know there is already a lock on this mutex.

So: how can this be done with `WaitforSingleObject()`-call? How can I find out if the related mutex is already locked?

I guess it has something to do with the `dwMilliseconds` parameter, but I don't understand how I can find out if it is locked or just returned because of an other lock...

Comment: Use `dwMilliseconds = 0` and examine the return value of [`WaitForSingleObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject)

Comment: "I know there is already a lock on this mutex" is a dangerous assumption and fraught with threading race bug risks.  At the moment you use the outcome of the test there is no guarantee whatsoever that the mutex is still in this state.  You also don't know how long ago the mutex was in that state, could be many seconds.  Even if you do this to implement "can't do it right now, go do something else" logic then you run the risk that the test constantly fails, even though it got unlocked between tests.  Impossible to debug since it only happens on a busy machine, the OS can't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "peeking" a mutex's current state. Either you lock the mutex or you don't, there is no peek.

`pthread_mutex_trylock()` always returns immediately and does not block the calling thread whether the mutex is already locked or not. However, if the mutex was not locked and `trylock` is successful then the lock has been obtained and you must unlock it. You must check the return value to know which is the case.

To replicate the same behavior with `WaitForSingleObject()`, simply set the timeout to 0 so it exits immediately without blocking. If the mutex is not already locked and the wait is successful, the lock is obtained and you must unlock it. Again, you must check the return value.

Note: there is a subtle but important difference between a pthread mutex and a Win32 mutex. A Win32 mutex is *always* recursive. When a thread already has a lock to a Win32 mutex, it can safely relock the same mutex without blocking itself. An internal lock count is incremented each time the mutex is relocked, and the thread simply needs to unlock the mutex as many times as it (re)locked in order to release the mutex for other threads to lock. A pthread mutex, on the other hand, is recursive only if the mutex creator explicitly requests it when calling `pthread_mutex_init()`. So be carefully with your (re)locking to avoid deadlocking your code.

Answer (score 4):

`WaitForSingleObject` (family of functions) is used for effectively putting a thread to sleep while waiting on various types of Windows handles. Execution of the thread will wait until the function has returned. In the simplest case of using mutex, these functions also request a lock. The thread will keep the mutex locked until you call `ReleaseMutex`.

`dwMilliseconds` merely specifies the wait timeout. Normally you should use the constant `INFINITE` here. You can also pass the value 0  to `dwMilliseconds` to have the function check the status of the handle and immediately return and continue execution. If it returns `WAIT_OBJECT_0` (or equivalent), you have the mutex lock. This is the equivalent to `pthread_mutex_trylock`.

In case you do specify a timeout, `WaitForSingleObject` will return a timeout status `WAIT_TIMEOUT` when it has not gotten the requested handle within the specified time period. In case of `WaitForMultipleObjects`, you also need to check the result to see which object you got.

Example from MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/using-mutex-objects

Comment: "*In case you do specify a timeout, WaitForSingleObject will return a timeout status WAIT_TIMEOUT when it has not gotten the requested handle within the specified time period.*" - even if you set the timeout to 0, it will still return `WAIT_TIMEOUT` if the mutex lock is not obtained immediately.